# Removing first digits from each line in bash (1-2 char length)

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am using jq command in bash to read data from json. One of the fields i take results in data such as this;

```
[
  "0local>aggr.tasks.max = 128",
  "1local>aggr.tasks.max = 128",
  "2local->aggi.tasks.max = 128",
  "3local>aggr.fetch.max.wait.ms = 150",
  "4local>aggr.fetch.max.wait.ms = 150",
  "5local->aggr.fetch.max.wait.ms = 150",
  "6local->aggr.fetch.min.bytes = 10485760",
  "7local>aggr-fetch.min.bytes = 10485760",
  "8local>aggr-fetch.min.bytes = 10485760",
  "9local->aggr.fetch.max.bytes = 52428800",
  "10local->aggr.fetch.max.bytes = 52428800",
  "11local->aggr.fetch.max.bytes = 52428800",
  "12local->aggr.max.request.size = 10485760",
  "13local->aggr-max.request.size = 10485760",
  "14local->aggr-max.request.size = 10485760"
]
```

I am trying to get rid of the starting digits.

The issues I face are;

1. If i use sed to remove the first digit, I face issues once it reaches 10, as now I have 2 digits
2. If i try to remove all numbers I also remove the value for each line

Can anyone help me with a simple solution to remove all digits that each line begins with, without it affecting the rest of the line?

Comment: Didn't forget. It just takes some time before you can mark as answered. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JQ that'd be way easier. E.g.:

```
jq 'map(sub("^\\d+";""))'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XjqqNuINeZ)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> If i use sed to remove the first digit, I face issues once it reaches
> 10, as now I have 2 digits

You should remove *all* digits *preceded by* a `"` character:

```
sed 's/"[0-9]*/"/'
```

The regular expression `"[0-9]*` (note that the double quote is literal here) matches zero or more consecutive occurrences of decimal digits preceded by a `"` character. This match is replaced with a `"` character, deleting these digits (if any), in effect.